# Url generation not giving desired results according to route config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4`.

I have a controller called `Server`, and 2 action methods called `Search` and `Component`.  I have the following route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute("Component",
     "{controller}/{serverId}/{action}",
     new { controller = "Server", action = "Component" },
     new { serverId = @"\d+" });
```

I am looking for a url similar to:

```
/Server/12345/Component
```

My Search action method:

```
return RedirectToAction("Component", new { serverId = 12345 });
```

My Component action method:

```
public ActionResult Component(int serverId)
{
     return View();
}
```

The url that is generated is:

```
/Server/12345/
```

It is wrong, it is leaving out "Component".  Why is this?

Comment: On a side note, this is a great thing to test your routes: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined Component as Default-Action, so why should it been appended?
If you want it in your route, then remove it from default and add it to your RedirectToAction call.

Answer (score 3):

```
     new { controller = "Server", action = "Component" },
```

Becase you are setting the default action to "Component", I think the link generation is smart enough to leave it off.